# Open Source Symfony2 projects

Tags: symfony

Are there any open source Symfony2 projects out there to which one can contribute?

We're starting a SF2 application and would like to see how serious Sf2 projects look like.

Didn't find any googling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius) ([website](http://sylius.com/)) is a full ecommerce project built on Symfony2.

Not only is it fully tested using some great PHP BDD tools (Behat & PhpSpec), it also has some great/advanced uses of bundle extensibility & configuration, re-usable models and *advanced* usage of the form component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. [Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) is one!

Other than that, [FriendsOfSymfony](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony) and [Sonata Project](https://github.com/sonata-project) bundles both have a fairly large code base and are widely used among Symfony2 developers.

Answer (score 0):

http://knpbundles.com/ is written using symfony and also accessible at github: https://github.com/knplabs/knpbundles